# Openpyxl update data of a file instead of creating a new

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, openpyxl

I´m building a little tool to check if hyperlinks on websites will dissapear or stay.
The program works so far, but always creates a new file and deletes the newest sheet which was created a day ago (i the script everyday).

My code is the following

```
    def save_results(excel_urls,erg):
        currentdate = str(date.today())
        excel_file = openpyxl.load_workbook('Links2.xlsx')
        excel_sheet = excel_file['Sheet']
        book = Workbook()
        sheet = book.active
        #this following code is from my main sheet to keep it in the following file as well. its also not a proper update function but works so far. 
        sheet.column_dimensions['A'].width = 60
        sheet.column_dimensions['B'].width = 60
        for row in excel_sheet.values:
            sheet.append(row)
        #Here im going to create the other sheets with the results of my crawl
        book.create_sheet(currentdate)
        book[currentdate].column_dimensions['A'].width = 60
        book[currentdate].column_dimensions['B'].width = 60
        for keys,values in enumerate(excel_urls):
            y = values[0], str(erg[keys])
            book[currentdate].append(y)
        book.save('Links2.xlsx')
```

I couldnt find a way to just update and not override the existing file. A function to include everything from a read before the results get safed would be working as well.

Thanks for your help in advance!

My function which doesn´t really work.

````
    excel_file = openpyxl.load_workbook('Links2.xlsx')
    book = Workbook()
    for z,i in enumerate(excel_file.sheetnames):
        book.create_sheet('{}'.format(i))
        print(excel_file.sheetnames[z])
        for row in excel_file[excel_file.sheetnames[i]].values:
            #print(row)
            excel_file[excel_file.sheetnames[i]].append(row)
    book.save('Links2.xlsx')```
````

Comment: There is no difference between updating and overwriting.

Comment: Thanks I was expecting that. So I tried to write a function which appends all existing data to the file, but it doesn´t work.
Gonna add the code in my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def save_exisiting_data():      
    excel_file = openpyxl.load_workbook('Links2.xlsx')
    book = Workbook(write_only=True)
    for z, i in enumerate(excel_file.sheetnames):
        book.create_sheet('{}'.format(i))
        book[i].column_dimensions['A'].width = 60
        book[i].column_dimensions['B'].width = 60
        for row in excel_file[excel_file.sheetnames[z]].values:
            book[excel_file.sheetnames[z]].append(row)
```